# Turn MBR disk partition to GPT to install Fedora on it

Tags: fedora, windows, gpt

I have windows 7 and want to install side by side Fedora 22. To install it I need to create GPT memory space.

To do so, I open Start>Computer>Management>Disk management. I have only one disk present in the system - my HD. And the option 'Convert to GPT disk' for it is greyed. I've seen some tutorials where people had several disks and changed MBR to GPT for a disk other than the one on which Win 7 is installed. But what should I do?

Is that possible to create a separate disk just to make it GPT? Or to make GPT only one partition of the existing disk and the rest will be MBR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk management can only convert a blank disk with all partitions deleted to GPT disk. You can use another software like AOMEI Partition Assistant to convert MBR disk to GPT disk.
There also is way to create a separate disk just to make it GPT, but I am not sure if it will allow you to install Fedora 22. You can create a virtual hard disk with disk management and then convert it to GPT disk.
to create VHD:

1. Right-click Disk Management and then click Create VHD. Follow the prompts that appear.
2. Right-click the new disk and then click Initialize Disk. Click OK.
3. Right-click the new disk and then click New Simple Volume (or select a different volume type, if available). Follow the prompts that appear.

Answer (score -1):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Convert_from_MBR_to_GPT
I've tested this solution and it was working, but I don't know how to install bootloader on GPT.

Comment: Hello Hepita - welcome to U&L! We encourage answers to stand on their own -- see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer; can you add the relevant parts from the link?